# Mocking a Constructor Helper Method in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have defined my constructor in the following fashion.

```
def __init__(self):
    //set some properties
    ...
    self.helperMethod()

def helperMethod(self):
    //Do some operation
```

I want to unittest the helper method, but in order to create the object to do the unit test, I need to run the `__init__` method. However, doing this calls the helper method, which is undesirable, because this is the method that I need to test.

I tried mocking out the `__init__` method, but I received the error that `__init__ should return None and not MagicMock`.

I also tried mocking out the helper method in the following way, but I could not find a way to manually restore the mocked method. MagicMock.reset_mock() does not do this.

```
SomeClass.helperMethod = MagicMock()
x = SomeClass()
[Need someway to undo the mock of helperMethod here]
```

What is the best way to unit test the helper method moving forward?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing the original value of `helperMethod` ?

```
original_helperMethod = SomeClass.helperMethod
SomeClass.helperMethod = MagicMock()
x = SomeClass()
SomeClass.helperMethod = original_helperMethod
```

You can also use the [`patch`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html) decorator from the `mock` library

```
from mock import patch

class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.helperMethod()

    def helperMethod(self):
        assert False, "Should not be called!"

x = SomeClass() # Will assert 
with patch('__main__.SomeClass.helperMethod') as mockHelpMethod:
    x = SomeClass() # Does not assert
```